# Is there a way in Java to generate random numbers following fixed mean and standard deviation?

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution

## Question

I know how to generate random numbers with a fixed mean and standard deviation.

I'd additionally like those values to be constrained to be within a range (I understand that this means the results won't be a true Gaussian distribution as a result, but a clipped Gaussian distribution)

## Context

The wider question I'm trying to answer is

> Assume you have a black box that gives out a monkey every 10 sec, the
> height of the monkey is between 24 and 36 inches. The height of the
> monkeys generated over half n hour follows a normal distribution with
> mean 30.5 inches and standard deviation 2.5. While there is another
> box in the room that causes a monkey to vanish if it’s height is below
> 28 inches, this happens every 20 secs. Write a program to calculate
> the number of monkeys left in the room after n-days (n is a user
> input). For the sake of logic assume room is large enough to
> accommodate an infinite number of monkeys and they have food.

Comment: [Random.nextGaussian()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29) is probably what you want.

Comment: I'm assuming this is part of an exercise you're doing. You've done a good job separating out the problem you're having from the whole exercise, but it would be nice to more clearly divide what your question is (I think the second paragraph) from whats just context (the first paragraph)

Comment: @VGR Random.nextGaussian() generates numbers following mean = 0 and std dev = 1. But I want to generate numbers following mean = 30.5 and std dev = 2.5

Comment: @RichardTingle I have to generate random numbers following mean = 30.5 and st dev = 2.5 within the range of 24 and 36.

Comment: @vikas you could affect the mean by adding to it, and I think you can affect the SD by multiplying the result of nextGausian()

Comment: Not sure what "within the range of 24 and 36" means though, is that a sharp cut off of the distribution rather than the extending to infinity of gaussian distribution?

Comment: @Vikas I've edited your question to better emphasis what you're trying to ask, feel free to correct it if I've got anything wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nextGaussian() method returns random numbers with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

This means that numbers returned by nextGaussian() will tend to "cluster" around 0, and that (approximately) 70% of values will be between -1 and 1. Based on the values returned by nextGaussian(), you can scale and shift them to get other normal distributions:

- to change the maen (average) of the distribution, add the required
  value;
- to change the standard deviation, multiply the value.

Examples:
to generate values with an average of 500 and a standard deviation of 100:

```
double val = r.nextGaussian() * 100 + 500;
```

to generate values with an average of 30.5 and a standard deviation of 2.5:

```
double val = r.nextGaussian() * 2.5 + 30.5;
```

with this 70% of values will be between 28 and 33. As 99.7% of the values lie in the 3-sigma range the height of the monkeys is between 24 and 36.

Comment: 3 sigma is 7.5, so the interval should be [30.5 - 7.5, 30.5 + 7.5], from 23 to 38, right?

Answer (score 0):

As [VGR mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) in their comment you can use [Random.nextGaussian()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29) to generate a  Gaussian distributed random number, with mean of zero and standard deviation of 1. You can affect the mean by adding to this value and affect the standard deviation by multiplying. So together you can generate random numbers with your derided properties. You'll want

```
desiredMean + desiredStandardDeviation * Random.nextGaussian()
```

You've stated an additional requirement that values must be within a range, you can achieve this easily by just re-rolling for a new value until you get one in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 17, Random and SecureRandom implement the interface RandomGenerator which has a new method [`nextGaussian(double mean, double stddev)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextGaussian(double,double))

OpenJDK Implementation is same as in previous answers:

```java
        default double nextGaussian(double mean, double stddev) {
           if (stddev < 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("standard deviation must be non-negative");

           return mean + stddev * RandomSupport.computeNextGaussian(this);
    }
```